# Why does Azure App Service Deploy task ignore the package in Drop folder?

Tags: azure-devops, ms-release-management

I am trying to use the "Deploy Azure App Service" task to deploy a website package. Just prior to this task in the Release, I have a task to run a powershell command to modify the WebApi.SetParameters.xml to modify app settings as per environment. 
I set the "Package or Folder" parameter of the Azure deploy task to point at the package zip file artifact in the drop folder.
However, the Task seems to ignore this zip file, and it refers back to a source folder according to its logs. 
Example:

**2016-11-16T13:07:10.2376125Z Verbose: Parameter entry 'DeploymentTestKey/1' is applicable to 'C:\agent_work\1\s\mysolution\myproject\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config' because of its scope.**

My question is, why is the task referring back to a package file in this folder when it should be acting on the content of the package zip file in the drop folder?

Comment: What's the value of Package or Folder? Share the detail release log here.

Comment: Can you share the settings of the task in your definition so that we can check the issue?